# 2 ssd harddisks into 1 partition

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I have 2 64GB SSD harddisks and I want to make 1 128GB partition from these 2 drives.
How can I achieve that? If there's a solution other than RAID, is it safer than RAID? (Since RAID is a little bit dangerous - data can be lost easily.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without using RAID you can mount one disk inside the other. This does not make a single partition across both disks, each will have a separate partition. You can create an empty directory and then go to Disk Management (start > run > diskmgmt.msc) and right click on the volume label for the second disk and select Change Drive Letter or Mount Point, and assign the mount point to the empty folder you've created. Essentially that hard drive, instead of being D: or E: or whatever, is now mounted inside that folder. You can then install applications or store data there, etc.

Though SSD failures in modern drives are a lot lower than traditional hard drives. As long as you do backups once in a while I wouldn't have a huge problem doing RAID 0 with two SSDs.

Comment: The hosting drive will have to be NTFS for this to work, which it probably is anyway. Just thought it was worth pointing this out.

Comment: Also of note, certain programs don't behave well when installed this way. Most of the accessing is completely and transparent - however I used to have steam installed in this manner and it would constantly complain about low disk space, even though the "folder" it was contained in had ample space available - just the host "C:" drive did not.

Comment: -1, that's not not 1 partition, that's just 2 hard drives in the same directory tree.

Comment: Seeing as there is no solution outside of RAID (or JBOD) on Windows and the OP clearly asked for alternative solutions I don't think this deserves a downvote.

Comment: i'll grant you it is an alternative.  but you're assuming the OP means "directory tree" when he says "partition".  make the downside clearer and i'll remove the downvote.

Comment: I think it's explained clearly enough in the first paragraph where I state that the second drive is mounted in the empty folder instead of having a drive letter.

Comment: much better, downvote removed.  your original was clear enough to powerusers but the exact implication of your alternative might be lost on those less knowledgeable.  thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Its really OS dependant, and raid type dependant- a mirrored raid is safer than a single disk, after all

With linux, you can use [LVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29) to have two physical volumes (or more) as a single logical volume or [dynamic disks on windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager)

Comment: +1 these solutions can put 1 partition on 2 drives.  could be expanded a bit though.